# AngularJS ng-show function with some show/hide not working as it should

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Im reaching out for a solution regarding a small angularJS directive using ng-show I have on a application. I have a header with three navigation icons. When you click on each of them a description of the icon will display to the user. It works as it should until you get to the last icon where it wants to show all the descriptions.

What is wrong with this code? Any suggestions would be appreciated:
this is a link showing what I am talking about: [demos screencast here](http://screencast.com/t/PmVci1K8nMh)

javascript:

```
$scope.brandingTitleToggle = function () {
        var brandingTitle = $('li.nav-branding');
        $(brandingTitle).on("click", function () {
            $scope.showFeesTitle = false;
            $scope.showSettingsTitle = false;
            $scope.showBrandingTitle = true;

        });

    };
    $scope.settingsTitleToggle = function () {
        var editorTitle = $('li.nav-editor');
        $(editorTitle).on("click", function () {
            $scope.showBrandingTitle = false;
            $scope.showFeesTitle = false;
            $scope.showSettingsTitle = true;

        });

    };
    $scope.feeTitleToggle = function (index) {
        var feesTitle = $('li.nav-fees');
        $(feesTitle).on("click", function (index) {
            $scope.showFeeTitle = false;
            $scope.showBrandingTitle = false;
            $scope.showSettingsTitle = false;
        });
    };
```

html

```
<ul class="list-inline">
            <li>What would you like to Do?</li>
            <li ui-sref-active="active" class="nav-branding"
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
                tooltip="Use this tool to Customize the Brand of your program"
                tooltip-placement="bottom">
                <a data-ng-click="brandingTitleToggle()" ui-sref="branding({ organizationId: organizationId, programId:programId })">Branding<span></span></a>
            </li>
            <li ui-sref-active="active" class="nav-editor"
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
                tooltip="Use this tool to Customize the Program"
                tooltip-placement="bottom">
                <a data-ng-click="settingsTitleToggle()" ui-sref="program-editor({ organizationId: organizationId, programId:programId })">Program Editor<span></span></a>
            </li>
            <li ui-sref-active="active" class="nav-fees"
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
                tooltip="Use this tool to add a fee to you program"
                tooltip-placement="bottom">
            <a data-ng-click="feeTitleToggle($index, $event)" ui-sref="fees({ organizationId: organizationId, programId:programId })">Program Fees<span></span></a>
            </li>
            <li data-ng-show="showBrandingTitle"><span class="navIconFade">branding settings</span></li>
            <li data-ng-show="showSettingsTitle"><span class="navIconFade">Program settings</span></li>
            <li data-ng-show="showFeeTitle"><span class="navIconFade">fee settings</span></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Why are you registering click events? You should just use `ng-click`.

Comment: @PSL Actually, he use both.

Comment: Yeah i saw that... Mix and match.. not good. .:)

Comment: with or without ng-click the same behavior happens

Answer (score 1):

You have a spelling mistake

`$scope.showFeesTitle = false;`

should be:

`$scope.showFeeTitle = false;`

Comment: Yeah, Im feeling like a dumb A** right about now. That explains everything and thank you